# How many different badges are there except those created by user?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, badges

What's the total of pre-set badges?

Comment: See also [List of all badges with full descriptions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67397/131247)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

38 Badges (as shown on the Badges page) on Meta.

I counted 40 on StackOverflow. They have the Beta and Fanatic badges, so that upped the count. I imagine the Beta badge will be on both SuperUser and ServerFault. I imagine that the Fanatic badge will be available for all the sites, but if they are not at the moment, they will be displayed as soon as someone hits 100 straight days (maybe?).

The tag badges are automatically created whenever someone first achieves 400 upvotes (for silver) and 1000 upvotes (for gold) in a single tag.

Comment: So badges won't be created if there are multiple tags even though it achieves 400 upvotes (for silver) and 1000 upvotes (for gold)?

Comment: I'm not sure I am following what you are saying. I know that tag badges are created when they hit 400 and 1000 upvotes by a single user (example, I have silver and gold discussion badge here on meta). If this isn't what you are talking about you may need to clarify yourself.

Comment: I mean one post gets many upvotes,but there are multiple tags(not single),will all the tags be created as badges or none of them will be created as badges?

Comment: @Shore No, not unless the post gets 400 upvotes it won't.

Comment: If you have a question with 5 different tags, and you post an answer that receives upvote, you will get credit for an upvote for each tag.